# grub rescue no file error

Tags: windows-8, grubrescue

I installed Ubuntu 13.04 along side windows 8 it works fine.

When I just use Ubuntu only but once I restart and use Windows and then switch off and again switch on something error displays with grub rescue and nothing more no Ubuntu no Windows only black.

I need help i have just begin using it I haven't tried anything.

Comment: try boot-repair.

Comment: you mean for windows

Comment: try the second option in [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have Ubuntu Live CD or Live USB. Normal session can be used to repair the grub. Boot using your Ubuntu Live CD or Live USB, while booting choose Try Ubuntu.

Once booted then open a terminal, and run the following command one by one to install the boot repair.

To add boot-repair to the repository

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
```

To Update your repository

```
sudo apt-get update
```

To install boot-repair

```
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
```

Once Installation complete run boot-repair on terminal by typing the following command or select it by System->Aministration->Boot Repair.

NOTE: Update the Boot Repair if its newer version is available.

It will scan the System for few seconds and will show you the options Recommended repair and Create a BootInfo summary. By clicking the Recommended Repair it will start repair the grub.